# Increase word space between words in small caps

Tags: spacing, fontspec, small-caps

With tracking activated for small caps, it can be a little bit hard to detect interword spaces. Cf. below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{Libertine Serif}[
        SmallCapsFeatures = {Letters = SmallCaps, LetterSpace = 5}]
\begin{document}
The title of my article is \textsc{This is the moment your life changed forever}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd like to increase the space between words in small caps, therefore, but *only* when words on either side are in small caps (i.e. there should be no extra space before the first word written in small caps or after the last word).

I would've thought I could do this by adding `WordSpace = <>` to `SmallCapsFeatures`, but this will change the interword space everywhere.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{Libertine Serif}[
        SmallCapsFeatures = {Letters = SmallCaps, LetterSpace = 5, WordSpace = 5}]
\begin{document}
The title of my article is \textsc{This is the moment your life changed forever}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I understand you want to be on the bleeding edge, but TeX distributions only feature the old versions of Libertine. Testing your code always requires changing the font name.

Comment: @egreg I see your point, but in order to use `\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}` too, you'd have to install the font on your system, right? (It being included in texlive doesn't mean it's a system font). So it doesn't require that much more to install Khaled Hosny's [libertine fork](https://github.com/khaledhosny/libertine) than to install a font found in TeX?

Comment: No, "Linux Libertine O" is distributed automatically with TeXLive and (full installations of) MikTeX. No need to go through any additional installation steps with "Linux Libertine O".

Comment: @Sverre Your code must be changed anyway, that's the problem.

Comment: @Mico I thought `\setmainfont` looked for system fonts. It also searches through the fonts in your TeX distribution? That's news to me, then, and would surely make @egreg's point even more pertinent.

Comment: I don't know how font discovery works under Xe(La)TeX. With Lua(La)TeX, all fonts that the utility program `luaotfload-tool` manages to locate and index -- from the man page: "luaotfload-tool: generate and query the Luaotfload font names database" -- can be handled with `\set[main,sans,mono,*]font`.

Comment: @egreg My code must be changed only beacuse it's not necessary to install a font as a system font if it's included in your tex distribution. I didn't know that. I thought you'd have to manually install those fonts as system fonts too when using `fontspec`. That's why I couldn't see the big difference between installing font x that comes with tex and installing font y that doesn't come with tex.

Comment: @egreg Here's [an example](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/264465/9077) of how setting `\setmainfont{<font name>}` for a font that comes with tex live that I haven't manually installed as a system font won't compile for me.

Comment: Many people have their systems configured to include the TL font directories in the system font search paths. I don't know about OS X or Windows, but this is pretty standard for everyone else. And there are lots of everyone else using TeX SE :-). Plus, it is very, very common for this everybody else to already have the relevant versions of Libertine installed in `/usr/share/fonts` also. If they are not already installed, they are almost certainly pre-packaged. The same is not true for the forked fonts. To use those I have to track them down and then create a package and then install it.

Answer (score 7):

You want to set `\spaceskip` to a non null value (and perhaps also `\xspaceskip`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}[
  SmallCapsFeatures = {
    Letters = SmallCaps,
    LetterSpace = 20,
  }
]

\xapptocmd{\scshape}
  {\spaceskip=3\fontdimen2\font plus 3\fontdimen3\font minus \fontdimen4\font
   \xspaceskip=2\fontdimen7\font}
  {}{}


\begin{document}

The title of my article is \textsc{This is the moment your life changed forever}.
Here the space is normal.

\end{document}
```

[image]

The values are of course exaggerated: here the interword space is set to three times the normal value.

When `\spaceskip` has a nonzero value, it is used for the interword space instead of the default font defined one. The relevant font parameters are

1. `\fontdimen2\font` (the natural width of the interword space)
2. `\fontdimen3\font` (the stretch component)
3. `\fontdimen4\font` (the shrink component)

Thus, specifying

```
\spaceskip=3\fontdimen2\font plus 3\fontdimen3\font minus \fontdimen4\font
```

we're telling to use three times the normal interword space, stretchable three times as much it is normally and shrinking it the same as the default. The parameter `\xspaceskip` is related to the space factor: when the space factor is >2000, TeX adds its value to the normal interword space (this is how the space is increased after periods); by default TeX uses `\fontdimen7\font`, but it uses `\xspaceskip` if it is nonzero.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your code here? I have no idea what numbers do what here, so I wouldn't know what to tweak in order to modify the interword space.

Comment: @Sverre I added a description

Comment: I have to admit that I didn't understand the bit about `\xspaceskip`. It also doesn't affect the spacing in this MWE.

Comment: @Sverre No, the space factor never enters into action because there's no punctuation. On the other hand, since Norwegian probably sets `\frenchspacing`, the space factor is completely irrelevant anyway.

Comment: I discovered a problem when using this in my document. It adds more vertical space between paragraphs instead of just using `\baselineskip`.

Comment: @Sverre I don't think so.

Comment: Then there's something else in my code that makes this happen when I add your code (it also happens when I add Steven's code with `\theskip`). I'll try (later) to figure out what the culprit is.

Answer (score 5):

Here, `\theskip` defines the new inter-word space inside `\textsc{}`.  EDITED to fix bug which chopped last word.  I also show that it works in headers in this MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\svtextsc\textsc
\def\theskip{\hspace{4ex}}
\def\textsc#1{\def\myskip{}\wspaceout#1 \relax\relax}
\def\wspaceout#1 #2\relax{%
  \myskip\svtextsc{#1}\let\myskip\theskip\ifx\relax#2\else\wspaceout#2\relax\fi}
% HEADER STUFF
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\lhead[\rm\thepage]{\textsc{Word1 Word2 Word3}}
\rhead[xxx]{\rm\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
The title of my article is \textsc{This is the moment your life changed forever}. 
And some more text

\def\theskip{\hspace{1.5ex}}
The title of my article is \textsc{This is the moment your life changed forever}. 
And some more text

\def\theskip{\ }
The title of my article is \textsc{This is the moment your life changed forever}. 
And some more text

\def\theskip{\hspace{2ex}}
The title of my article is \textsc{This is the moment your life changed forever}. 
And some more text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When I try this code, the third (and final) word in my header (which is like `textsc{Word1 Word2 Word3}`) disappears ...

Comment: @Sverre Using `fancyhdr` package, I can confirm the problem.  Now let me think why...

Comment: @Sverre Actually, foolish me did not realize the problem exists even in normal text.  Let me fix it.

Comment: @Sverre Fixed now.

Comment: `\rm` -> `\rmfamily`? Or do you want the non-2e meaning? But then this might not work and `\normalfont\rmfamily` would be better? Possibly?

Comment: Is there a way to also redefine \scshape to include this?

Comment: @ezgranet I don't believe that this approach would allow that.  However, there may be something possible with the `\spaceskip` parameter, for example, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/600615/texttt-and-breaking-in-justified-paragraphs/600638#600638

Answer (score 3):

Imho `fontspec` could do better here and allow `WordSpace` to be set for small caps alone. The following is *not* meant as usable document code -- it redefines an internal command of fontspec and probably miss some cleaning up -- but only as proof of concept:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\ExplSyntaxOn\makeatletter
\cs_set:Nn \__fontspec_declare_shapes_smcaps:nn
 {
    \tl_if_empty:NF \l__fontspec_nfss_sc_tl
     {
      \__fontspec_DeclareFontShape:xxxxxx {\l__fontspec_nfss_enc_tl} {\l_fontspec_family_tl} {#1}
        { \__fontspec_combo_sc_shape:n {#2} } {\l__fontspec_nfss_sc_tl} {\l__fontspec_postadjust_tl
         \l__uf_fontspec_postadjust_sc_tl
        }
     }
  }

 \tl_set:Nn \l__uf_fontspec_postadjust_sc_tl
     {
      \fontdimen 2 \font = 5 \fontdimen 2 \font
      \fontdimen 3 \font = 5 \fontdimen 3 \font
      \fontdimen 4 \font = 5 \fontdimen 4 \font
     }

\ExplSyntaxOff      

 \setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}[
        SmallCapsFeatures = {Letters = SmallCaps, LetterSpace = 5,}
           ]

\ExplSyntaxOn
%should not affect Arial:
 \tl_clear:N \l__uf_fontspec_postadjust_sc_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff 
 \setsansfont{Arial}    
\begin{document}
The title of my article is

\textsc{This is the moment your life changed forever}.

{\large \scshape Large: the title of my article} 

\textsc{\bfseries the title of my article}

the title of my article 

\sffamily some words in sans 

\scshape some words in small caps sans

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you perhaps suggest an improvement along these lines at [`fontspec`'s Github page](https://github.com/wspr/fontspec)? I could also do it, but I would just link to your answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem should be solved by using `\caps` command form `soul` package.
An example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}
\begin{document}
   \scshape{abcde fghijk lmnopqr stuvwxyz abcdefghij klmnopqr stuvwxyz}

   \caps{abcde fghijk lmnopqr stuvwxyz abcdefghij klmnopqr stuvwxyz}
\end{document}
```

You can change the font, spacing and even the command in use with command `\capsdef`.

Usage:

```
\capsdef{<font>}{<command>}{<inter-letter space>}{<inner space>}{<outer space>}
```

It seems that you want to increase `<inner-space>`. It can be done as follows:

```
\capsdef{T1/ppl/m/n/5-15}{\scshape}{.16em}{.6em}{.2em}
```

This also sets the command to `\scshape` so you won't need to use `\caps`.

Comment: An example of usage?

Comment: @egreg Example added :)

Comment: I am not sure if it does exactly what OP asked for, but the sole purpose of this command is to increase spacing properly in small caps words and it solves problem with hyphenation. So, it could be usefull for the OP.