# Problem with interword spacing in LuaLaTeX

Tags: spacing, luatex, fontspec, microtype

I have a problem with LuaLaTeX and interword spacing using fontspec. This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX, Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=Common,
  SmallCapsFeatures={Renderer=Basic},
  ]{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}

\LARGE\addfontfeatures{LetterSpace=30.0}
THIS IS A TEST

\end{document}
```

This is the output:

[image]

As you can see, the interword space remains unchanged as the interchar space (letterspace) has augmented (in fact, it is even smaller than it). I had assumed the latter would change proportionally with respect to the former, *as it actually happens when compiled using XeLaTeX*. See the output of the same code compiles with XeLaTeX

[image]

How can I fix this automatically (i.e. without having to fiddle with fontspec's `WordSpace` argument)?

(I'm running TeXLive 2015 in Xubuntu Linux 15.10, with the latest updates. (LuaLaTeX version beta-0.80.0 (TeX Live 2015) (rev 5238).))

Comment: Which TeX distribution, which vintage of both LuaTeX and XeTeX, and which version of `fontspec` in installed on your system? The reason I ask is that on my system -- MacTeX2015, LuaTeX 0.80.0, XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992, fontspec 2.4e -- the outcome is the same when I compile your MWE under LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX; what I get corresponds to the first of the two screenshots you've posted.

Comment: See updated answer for that.

Comment: Instead of `SmallCapsFeatures={Renderer=Basic}`, use something like `SmallCapsFeatures={LetterSpace=5}`.  There’s no need for `Renderer=Basic` here.

Comment: @Thérèse Thanks, although it is unrelated (it doesn't fix the problem).

Comment: I'd use something like `\textls[200]{THIS IS A TEST}`.

Comment: @Thérèse It happens with all fonts; I think `LetterSpace` is broken in LuaTeX.

Comment: @Thérèse Yes, I tested it with other fonts and the problem persists.

Comment: @egreg Not sure what to expect from using `\textls[200]{THIS IS A TEST}` . I seem to get no change in the letter spacing.

Comment: Does your version of Times New Roman have the `cpsp` feature? `Kerning=Uppercase` is not broken, and it may serve your immediate needs, though it’s very unlikely to give you as much spacing as you seem to want.

Comment: @NVaughan It's the `microtype` way of specifying letter spacing. Remove the `\addfontfeature` instruction.

Comment: @egreg I don't understand. I need the extra spacing in that line. What you're saying is that I should request it using `microtype` instead of `fontspec`?

Comment: @NVaughan Yes, that's what I'm saying. With `\textls` (pr `\lsstyle`, which is the corresponding declaration) it works, at least on my machine.

Comment: @Thérèse No, it doesn't.

Comment: @egreg So I can either add `WordSpace=3.0` to `fontspec` or instead use `microtype`'s `\lsstyle[3000]{...}`, right? Is this a bug?

Comment: Monkeying with `WordSpace` is not recommended. I said in a previous comment that `LetterSpace` seems to be broken in LuaTeX. But using `microtype` features seems to work. Don't confuse `\textls` with `\lsstyle`.

Comment: The latest version of `luaotfload`, which is just making its way to CTAN mirrors today, seems to have fixed this problem.  :-)

Comment: @egreg This bug is still present, contrary to what github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/issues/297 says, isn't it? I tested egreg's example and the six letters are still rendered as "A_B_C_D_E_F", not "A_B__C_D__E_F". Used LuaTeX Version 0.95.0 (TeX Live 2016), luaotfload-letterspace.lua is v2.7 but part of the 2.8rc3 bundle.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's try simplifying the example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\begin{document}

\addfontfeatures{LetterSpace=30.0}

AB CD EF

\showoutput

\end{document}
```

This is the relevant part from the log file when compiling with LuaLaTeX:

```
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x15.0, direction TLT
....\EU2/LatinModernRoman(1)/m/n/10 A
....\kern 3.0
....\EU2/LatinModernRoman(1)/m/n/10 B
....\glue 3.33 plus 1.66331 minus 1.1111
....\EU2/LatinModernRoman(1)/m/n/10 C
....\kern 3.0
....\EU2/LatinModernRoman(1)/m/n/10 D
....\glue 3.33 plus 1.66331 minus 1.1111
....\EU2/LatinModernRoman(1)/m/n/10 E
....\kern 3.0
....\EU2/LatinModernRoman(1)/m/n/10 F
```

and here's the same when XeLaTeX is used:

```
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x15.0
....\EU1/LatinModernRoman(1)/m/n/10 AB
....\glue 6.33 plus 3.16182 minus 2.1121
....\EU1/LatinModernRoman(1)/m/n/10 CD
....\glue 6.33 plus 3.16182 minus 2.1121
....\EU1/LatinModernRoman(1)/m/n/10 EF
```

The model used for representing letter spacing is different, so XeTeX doesn't show the interletter kerns. However, this shows where LuaLaTeX (or more probably `luaotfload`) goes wrong: in XeTeX also the interword space is multiplied by the spacing factor, which it isn't in LuaTeX.

Between the two letter groups we have

```
....\glue 3.33 plus 1.66331 minus 1.1111
```

in LuaTeX, while it is

```
....\glue 6.33 plus 3.16182 minus 2.1121
```

If I remove the `\addfontfeatures` line, the glue is the same in both engines.

If I change the font to Times New Roman, I get

```
....\glue 2.5 plus 1.24875 minus 0.83415
```

in LuaTeX (just like when `LetterSpace` is not added), but

```
....\glue 5.5 plus 2.74724 minus 1.83516
```

in XeTeX.

To make the bug clear: in XeTeX the amount of letter spacing is also added to the interword space, but this is not done in LuaTeX.

My suggestion is to use `microtype` letter spacing in LuaLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}

\textls[400]{AB CD EF}

\showoutput

\end{document}
```

produces

```
....\EU2/TimesNewRoman(0)/m/n/10/400ls A
....\EU2/TimesNewRoman(0)/m/n/10/400ls B
....\glue 3.5 plus 1.24875 minus 0.83415
....\EU2/TimesNewRoman(0)/m/n/10/400ls C
....\EU2/TimesNewRoman(0)/m/n/10/400ls D
....\glue 3.5 plus 1.24875 minus 0.83415
....\EU2/TimesNewRoman(0)/m/n/10/400ls E
....\EU2/TimesNewRoman(0)/m/n/10/400ls F
```

which is comparable to the XeTeX output and the result is

[image]

Here is a plain TeX example:

```
\input ifluatex.sty

\ifluatex
  \input luaotfload.sty
  \font\test=LatinModernRoman:mode=node;script=latn;language=DFLT;+tlig;+trep;letterspace=30
\else
  \font\test="Latin Modern Roman/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;letterspace=30"
\fi
\test

AB CD EF

\tracingoutput=1
\tracingonline=1
\showboxbreadth=\maxdimen
\showboxdepth=\maxdimen

\bye
```

If run with LuaTeX, the output shows

```
...\test A
...\kern 2.7
...\test B
...\glue 3.087 plus 1.54195 minus 1.03003
...\test C
...\kern 2.7
...\test D
...\glue 3.087 plus 1.54195 minus 1.03003
...\test E
...\kern 2.7
...\test F
```

If run with XeTeX, it shows

```
...\test AB
...\glue 6.33 plus 3.16182 minus 2.1121
...\test CD
...\glue 6.33 plus 3.16182 minus 2.1121
...\test EF
```

so the problem is not due to interaction with LaTeX. If the `letterspace` bit is removed, the interword glue turns out to be `3.087pt` with LuaTeX and `3.33pt` with XeTeX.

Comment: Isn't this the same problem as I addressed in [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/264224/increase-word-space-between-words-in-small-caps), for which you also provided an answer (but a very different one)?

Comment: @Sverre I don't think so; I believe that in that context only XeLaTeX was of a concern. The problem was different, anyway.

Comment: @egreg make a plain example and report on luatex list?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm inclined to think it's more `luaotfload` than LuaTeX.

Comment: @egreg yes but the main part of that is extracted from context so pinging Hans on luatex list still works:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: The code (luaotfload-letterspace.lua) says in various place that "it is far inferior to the original" (context code) and "is quite
inefficient compared to Context’s attribute based approach, but Xetex
compatibility reduces our options significantly." So imho luaotfload is probably the part which must be improved.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Well I can't improve luaotfload, but I can add an issue. But I'm not quite sure that it is a bug or only a nuisance, after all you can change the word space too. It would be also interesting to know if there is luatex counterpart to `\pdfinterwordspaceon`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer `WordSpace` changes `\fontdimen` and acts globally.

Comment: @egreg: Yes I know, but normally I would add LetterSpace to a specific font face anyway (and not through \addfontfeatures), so imho it wouldn't matter much.