# Inconsistent letterspacing (interword space) in pdflatex vs lualatex

Tags: pdftex, luatex, microtype, letterspacing

In my documents I prefer text in small- and all-caps to be letter spaced. To that end I am using the letterspacing capabilities of the `microtype` package. Until now (with version 2.5 of `microtype`) I used to get the exact same result when the text was typeset in the same font via the `pdflatex` and `lualatex` engine, but after the update to latest version of `microtype` (2.6) I noticed that while the tracking between characters is the same in both engines, the interword space is not adjusted when the document is run with `lualatex`, giving a less readable and pleasing result, especially in all-caps text. I have tested many fonts that I have available in both opentype and type1 format and the behaviour is consistent. The problem is illustrated in the following images (using the freely available libertine font):

[image: luatex vs pdftex output: Better interword space in pdftex, no adjustment with luatex]

An MWE is provided as well:

```
\documentclass[12pt,crop]{standalone}
\usepackage{ifluatex}
\ifluatex
\usepackage{luatex85}
\else
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\fi
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{letterspace}
%\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{textcase}
\def\allcapsspacing{}
\def\smallcapsspacing{}
\renewcommand{\allcapsspacing}[1]{\textls*[150]{#1}}
\renewcommand{\smallcapsspacing}[1]{\textls*[50]{#1}}
\newcommand{\allcaps}[1]{\allcapsspacing{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}}
\newcommand{\smallcaps}[1]{\smallcapsspacing{\scshape\MakeTextLowercase{#1}}}
\begin{document}
Stop \smallcaps{Stealing Sheep} Stop \allcaps{Stealing Sheep}\par
\end{document}
```

Does anybody have an idea why it happens and/or how I could get a similarly adjusted interword space, while not having to adjust it manually (via `\spaceskip`) or to rely on `fontspec`'s `\LetterSpace` command? Possibly related: [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276426/problem-with-interword-spacing-in-lualatex) and [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/264224/increase-word-space-between-words-in-small-caps)

Comment: I'm not sure what's happening here. I tested not loading the `letterspace` and the `textcase` packages, and tuning the `microtype` options, but with no avail. My hunch is that different fonts are being loading in each case. Using `pdffonts` (from `poppler`), in the PDFLaTeX case, I find that the "TKDTHA+LinLibertineT (Type 1)" font is being loaded; in the LuaLaTeX case, I get two fonts: "VLTBVA+LinLibertineO  CID Type 0C Identity-H" and "PHHVVI+LinLibertineO CID Type 0C Identity-H".

Comment: @NVaughan: Thanks for having a look. According to my understanding the font LinLibertineT is just the type 1 (.pfb file) version of LinLibertineO (opentype otf), hence the letter T. I do not think that the problem is font specific because it happens with every font I tried (e.g. FiraSans), but rather engine specific and perhaps something in the inner workings of `luaotfload` and the way letterspacing is implemented there. Unfortunately, my lua skills are limited to be able to elaborate on that :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct behaviour in `LuaTeX`'s letterspacing/tracking seems to have returned with the most recent version of `luaotfload` (`v2.96` 2019/02/14). From the documentation:

> In version 2.95 letterspacing was broken due to a change in the fontloader (issue
>   38). This has been repaired. At the same time a number of oddities and bugs in
>   the letterspacing has been corrected[...]

The `letterspace` and `microtype` packages (from `v2.7b` 2019/02/28) also behave as expected now.

Answer (score 2):

I see the same issue when using the Lucida OpenType fonts with LuaLaTeX, as well as with the Libertine fonts. There's [another thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276426/problem-with-interword-spacing-in-lualatex) that gets into the fine details of what appears to be a small issue in LuaTeX. I found that I could gain control in LuaLaTeX by using Microtype's commands to adjust interword spacing, e.g.:

```
\SetTracking[
  spacing = {500*,100*,}, % choose values you like
  outer kerning = {*,*} 
  ] 
  {encoding = *}
  { 50 }  % choose a value you like
```

and then invoking `\textls{\scshape{Stop stealing sheep!}`.  Microtype without manually increased interword the spacing seems to leave too little space between words when the interletter spacing is made rather large (e.g., 200/1000 em for some heading text).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did make some progress playing around with the settings, but the result is still not as desired. Using the `\SetTracking` command, applies the setting _on top_ of the argument of `\textls*[]{}`. I will have a closer, more rigorous look and post again. I am accepting this as an answer for now. Thanks again.