# Word spacing with tracking in lualatex

Tags: spacing, luatex, microtype, letterspacing

What is the right way to do tracking in LuaLaTeX at the moment?

My problem is basically the same as in the older question [Problem with interword spacing in LuaLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276426/problem-with-interword-spacing-in-lualatex).

However, the answer given by egreg does not seem to work anymore.

In particular the output seems to depend on whether I include the % in front of \setmainfont in the following or not (using \setmainfont makes the extra interword spacing disappear, which is not what I want).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}

\begin{document}

\textls[400]{AB CD EF}

\showoutput

\end{document}
```

I'm using TeX Live 2017 (from Arch Linux repositories), the version of LuaLaTeX is 1.0.4 and the version of microtype is 2.7.

Comment: I suggest that you write to the microtype author.

Comment: Indeed, if I compile the example (with the `\setmainfont` line) I get wrong spacing using TeX Live 2017 and 2016, but the expected output with TeX Live 2015.